# An exercise regarding polynomials

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I guess it is a simple exercise though I'm not very good at polynomials. It asks:

Find $m,n,p,q$ natural numbers such that the polynomial $X^m+X^n+X^p+X^q$ is divisible by $x^3+x^2+x+1$.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For you "natural" include zero? Because if it does then choose simply $\;m=3\,,\,n=2\,,\,p=1\,,\,q=0\;$ ...:)

Comment: It doesn't mention ..well it's easy to guess that answer but I think i have to prove why that is the answer.

Comment: Well, that is **an** answer and it is as easy to prove it as you can expect...you could also prove with $\;m=n=p=q=0\;$, or even $\;m=n=q=0\;,\;p=1\;$ , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general method for finding as many such sets of natural numbers as you like:

1. Choose a natural number $k$
2. Multiply $(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ by $x^k$ to get $(x^{k+3}+x^{k+2}+x^{k+1}+x^k)$
3. Obviously, $(x^{k+3}+x^{k+2}+x^{k+1}+x^k)$ is divisible by  $(x^3+x^2+x+1)$
4. Then, your natural numbers are $m=k+3$, $n=k+2$, $p=k+1$, $q=k$

Comment: Yes I believe this is the best solution

Comment: Unfortunately it is incomplete. $X^{4000}+X^{401}+X^{42}+X^3$ is also a solution for example

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy: For the question at hand, which asks for **one** solution (and not **all** solutions), it is definitely complete!!!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$1+x+x^2+x^3=(1+x)+x^2(1+x)=(1+x)(1+x^2)$$

Comment: Hmm. Very nice factorization, but it’s not very helpful here. I find your hint unconvincing.

Comment: Yes well it is easy to see that and i did that though I couldn't see the use of it

Comment: I think this is a rather good hint. +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint : show that $X^m+X^n+X^p+X^q$ is divisible by $X^3+X^2+X+1$ iff $m,n,p,q$ form a complete set of residues modulo $4$. Note that the value of a power $X^j$ modulo $X^3+X^2+X+1$ only depends on the value of $j$ modulo $4$.

In other words, the most general solution to your problem is $X^{4q_1}+X^{4q_2+1}+X^{4q_3+2}+X^{4q_4+3}$ where $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$ are nonnegative integers.

Comment: Sounds great though it would be of great help to see it solved.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial answer is when m=3, n=2, p=1 and q=0 and m=n=p=0 and q=1. This is because the polynomial divides itself.

Non-trivial answers may be obtained by multiplying the polynomial with other polynomial with no constant coefficient, like x, x+x^2, x+x^3, x^2+x^5, etc.

Hope this helps